# Using VBA subroutine to change value of current cell for entire column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to convert latitude and longitude to degrees in VBA. I want to write subroutine to overwrite the entire column into degrees. I want it to iterate through the entire column but it only works for the current cell. I have used offset to move the cell. But does not help

```
Sub autoConvertToDegree()
    Dim sign As Integer
    Dim position As Integer
    Dim temp As String
    Dim tok As Variant
    Do
        sign = 0
        position = 0
        tok = Null

        temp = ActiveCell.Value
        sign = IIf(Left(temp, 1) = "-", -1, 1)
        position = InStr(temp, "+")
        If (position > 0) Then Mid(temp, position) = " "
        position = InStr(temp, "-")
        If (position > 0) Then Mid(temp, position) = " "
        temp = Replace(temp, "'", " ")
        temp = Replace(temp, """", " ")
        temp = LTrim(temp)
        tok = Split(temp, " ")
        ActiveCell.Value = sign * (tok(0) + tok(1) / 60# + tok(2) / 3600#)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop While Application.IsText(ActiveCell.Value)
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you used a break point to run through the code to see where errors occur? At a glance using `ActiveCell` could cause problems.

Comment: error occur in ActiveCell.Value = sign * (tok(0) + tok(1) / 60# + tok(2) / 3600#)

Comment: What are the values in `tok`? Are there any?

Answer (score 1):

A preferred method for looping through cells is to use the `for each c in rng` and in your example I'd do the following:

```
Sub autoConvertToDegree()
    Dim sign As Integer
    Dim position As Integer
    Dim temp As String
    Dim tok As Variant

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A100")
        If Application.IsText(c) Then
            sign = 0
            position = 0
            set tok = Nothing '<~~ set variant to nothing

            temp = c
            sign = IIf(Left(temp, 1) = "-", -1, 1)
            position = InStr(temp, "+")
            If (position > 0) Then Mid(temp, position) = " "
            position = InStr(temp, "-")
            If (position > 0) Then Mid(temp, position) = " "
            temp = Replace(temp, "'", " ")
            temp = Replace(temp, """", " ")
            temp = LTrim(temp)
            tok = Split(temp, " ")
            c = sign * (tok(0) + tok(1) / 60# + tok(2) / 3600#)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```